# eclipse checkstyle plugin : CustomImportOrder

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am using Eclipse photon.
Check style plugin : 8.12.0.201808161509

I have a custom CustomImportOrder section.

```
        <module name="CustomImportOrder">
            <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
            <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="false"/>
            <property name="specialImportsRegExp" value="^com\.xxx\."/>
            <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###SPECIAL_IMPORTS"/> 
        </module>
```

I did :

- Import my checkstyle.xml file in the Preferences -> Checkstyles.
- Configure Eclipse -> Pref -> Java -> Code Style -> Organisse Import
  to reflects this.
- Create a Pref -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter using the Checkstyle plugin.

When I fire a **Maven build, the checkstyle plugin runs just fine**, as Eclipse has formatted my code correctly

But when I click on my project, and CheckStyle -> Check code with CheckStyle, I get :

> Wrong lexicographical order for 'com.xxx' import. Should be before
>   'java.yyy'.

I get other validation errors as well

Any ideas?

I double check, and my config is the default config in checkstyle (not using the "sun" or "google" built-in configs.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying the project (not the workspace) and starting eclipse with -clean, and re-importing the project solved the issue